# Proof in "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic » by Herbert Enderton

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, quantifier-elimination

I’m studying section 3.2 in Herbet Enderton’s "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic" and I can’t seem to find a justification for something in a proof. The domain of the structures we are dealing is the Natural numbers, however, when substracting terms, one may end up with negative values and it is not justified why this can be written nonetheless.

You can see this for example here:
[image]

Here, terms $r_i$ and $s_i$ are terms not containing $x$, but nothing assures us that $r_i-s_i$ is not negative, hence going out of our domain.

The writer kinda acknowledges this later but he only seems to find it problematic if every $r_i-s_i$ are negative, in this case he provides a solution to this.

My question here is why is it only a problem if they are all negative since we don't have negative numbers at all.

Thank you all in advance and sorry if the question is not detailed enough. I will make improvents if needed.

Comment: See page 198: we have $ny +t = u$ and the author introduce as **abbreviation** the subtraction: $ny = u − t$. Thus, by definition $u$ is greater that $t$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but in that case it doesn't make much sense that he admits the case where every $r_i-s_i$ is negative.

Comment: As Mauro said, $r_i-s_i<x$ is just an abbreviation for $r_i<x+s_i$, so $r_i-s_i$ is undefined. It is not supposed to be an element of the domain.

Comment: @AnneBauval okay so basically I do not need to worry about it being negative because it is not even supposed to denote an actual element, it's just a simpler way to organize our formulas? This is being hard to process sorry

Comment: Usually, subtraction on $N$ would be defined as follows: $\forall x, y, z \in N: [x-y=z \iff x=z+y]$. It seems to me that Enderton has defined it the most bizarre way here.

Comment: I do not have access to the Book & I do not have the context of the Situation. One thought occurs to me about the Specific query "why is it only a problem if they are all negative" : (A) If all LHS terms in the InEqualities are Negative (eg $-100,-99,-95,-85 \le x$) then we get Equivalent Single InEquality with Negative LHS (that is $-85 \le $) & $x$ itself may have Negative value to satisfy the InEquality. BIG PROBLEM (B) If not all LHS terms are Negative & atleast term is Positive (eg 8) then the Equivalent Single InEquality is $8 \le x$, & we have no Issue because $x$ has to be Positive.